# Google Address Api not displaying search result in IE9 but data gets populated to address fields

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, internet-explorer-9, google-maps-api-2

In am testing google API in IE browser using developer tools IE9 mode. The search result not showing but data is getting populated to the address fields. I spending hours to try and edit .pac-container and .pac-item. Nothing seems to be working. I could change color, width of dropdown using pac container, pac item but still address not visible to user eyes even though the data got filled up finally.

I am aware google api is not officaily supported for IE9. Before we inform all our users to upgrade their system, I am doing this as temporary workaround.

The Issue I see here is dropdown data is not visible to user, so i am thinking changing any css style would make it visible, remaining all functionality works fine.

[image: Search Result]

[image: Data populated after selection]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }  

<!-- .pac-item { -->
    <!-- display: block !important; -->
    <!-- font-size: 14px; -->
    <!-- color: #999 -->
<!-- } -->
    </style>


    <style>

      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
        font-family: "Roboto";
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f9ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
      .pac-container {
        z-index: 10000 !important;
        display: block !important;
}

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete"
             placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()"
             type="text"/>
    </div>

    <!-- Note: The address components in this sample are typical. You might need to adjust them for
               the locations relevant to your app. For more information, see
         https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
    -->

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true"/></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route" disabled="true"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"/></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="country" disabled="true"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
// This sample uses the Autocomplete widget to help the user select a
// place, then it retrieves the address components associated with that
// place, and then it populates the form fields with those details.
// This sample requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script
// src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var placeSearch, autocomplete;

var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
  // geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {types: ['geocode']});

  // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
  // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
  autocomplete.setFields(['address_component']);

  // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
  // address fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details,
  // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle(
          {center: geolocation, radius: position.coords.accuracy});
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=dummyKey&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

After using F12 developer tools to check the dropdown items, it seems that it is populated by Google API, so, if you want to change it, you might need to override the Google API, might be is very hard, and as [the document](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport) said, the Google Map JavaScript API support IE 10 and 11. So, I think it is better to upgrade the IE browser version to IE 11, this might be is the easiest way to display the items.

Besides, here is another choice, you could try to use the AutocompleteService instead of Autocomplete, after retrieving the Autocomplete Predictions, you could manually filter the list of results and use an autocomplete plugin to display the items.

Please refer to the following link to learn how to retrieve Autocomplete Predictions:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction

Answer (score -1):

From [the (current) documentation](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport) (doesn't include IE9):

**Supported browsers:**

- The current version of Microsoft Edge (Windows)
- Internet Explorer 10 and 11 (Windows; Compatibility View is not supported.)
- The current and previous version of Firefox (Windows, macOS, Linux)
- The current and previous version of Chrome (Windows, macOS, Linux)
- The current and previous version of Safari (macOS)

Comment: Hi, I am aware it is not supported for IE9. I am trying to do some workaround for IE9 temporarily. The issue here is, the dropdown value is not visible to user, remaining all fucntions work as expected.

Comment: It would be good if you added that information to yout question.